# Trying to clone an id and create a hidden field with the value of an existent text field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm extremely new to using jQuery/JavaScript, so please don't judge me if this is a somewhat stupid question :).

What I want to do is create a hidden field with the value of  `name='link_x'`, `x` representing a random number, each time the `<div class="delete_button">` containing the same id selector as the class selector of `name='link_x'` is clicked.

This is what I had in mind, but it doesn't seem to be working:

**My JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('div.delete_button').click( function() {
                var buttonId = $(this).attr('id');
                var inputVal = $('input').hasClass(buttonId).val();

                var num     = $('.clonedInput').length;
                var newNum  = new Number(num + 1);

                var newElem = $('#hidden' + num).clone().attr('id', 'input' + newNum);

                newElem.children(':first').attr('name', 'link[' + newNum + ']').val(inputVal);
                $('#input' + num).after(newElem);

                $(this).css('display','none');
    });
});
```

**My HTML:**

```
<form action="delete-func.php" method="post">
<div id="hidden1" class="clonedInput">
<input name="link[1]" type="hidden"  value="http://www.google.com/" />
</div>
<input class="1" name="del_link" type="text" value="http://www.euieuek.com" /><div id="1" class="delete_button" style="color: red; cursor: pointer;">X</div>
<input type="submit" value="Delete from records!" />
</form>
```

Any edits, answers, comments would be very much appreciated! Please ask for more information if you think what I've currently given is obscure!

:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
var inputVal = $('input').hasClass(buttonId).val();
```

to

```
  var inputVal = $('input.'+ buttonId).val();
```

Comment: Thanks :). I'll accept your answer in a minute when the timer drops.